# `%l` encoding in terminfo parameterized strings

Tags: terminal, c++14, ncurses, terminfo, termcap

I am implementing a parser in C++ for parameterized strings(which are used for specifying some terminal capabilities for a terminal). Then I came across this `% encoding` on the [man page](https://man.cx/terminfo(4)) of terminfo:

```
                                 %l   push strlen(pop)
```

So, my question is, that whenever we are pushing anything onto the stack, it is when any these following `% encodings` are encountered:

```
%p[1-9]        push ith parm
%’c’           push char constant c
%{nn}          push decimal constant nn
%l             push strlen(pop)
%+ %− %* %/ %m (arithmetic):   push(pop integer2 op pop integer1)
%& %| %^ (bit operations):     push(pop integer2 op pop integer1)
%= %> %< (logical operations): push(pop integer2 op pop integer1)
%A %O (logical operations):    and, or
%! %~ (unary operations):      push(op pop)
```

And whenever these are encountered and their results are computed and when the results are about to be pushed onto the stack, **then either an integer(including 0 or 1 for bool results) or a character are going to be pushed onto the stack**, then does `%l encoding` mean any or none of the following:

- pop a single value from the stack and `if a character push 1 onto stack` and `if an integer push #digits_in_that_integer onto the stack`.
- (since `%l` is written in [manpages](https://man.cx/terminfo(4)) using `strlen`) pop a string from the stack (to pop a string: keep popping untill the stack is empty), and then push back the length of popped string onto the stack.

**So, my question is what does `%l push strlen(pop)` mean, which length is it talking about ?**

*Bonus question: Is the way to pop a string in case of parameterized strings of terminfo (in the 2nd bullet point mentioned above), correct ?*

Edit: As pointed by *Thomas Dickey*, now I am referring to [this man page of terminfo](https://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notwithstanding the page title ***"Linux Manpages Online"***, the manual page referred to is Solaris (SVr4), which was obsoleted by X/Open Curses.  Neither gives the necessary details; ncurses' interpretation fills in the details:

- SVr4 (and X/Open, which regurgitates that information without adding clarity) says that the parameters for [`tparm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/tparm.html) are "long".  But some of the parameters have to be strings (i.e., `char*`), to support the label capabilities.
- at the time that `tparm` was first documented, `long` seemed big enough to hold a pointer (i.e., `char*`, a *string*), and `<stdarg.h>` was not common practice.  That assumption about "big enough" isn't necessarily true (see the discussion in the 20-year-old [*64-Bit Programming Models: Why LP64?*](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html)), but it's the assumption made for `tparm`.
- for the platforms you're most interested in, assume you have LP64 (or LP32).
- when you call `tparm`, ncurses analyzes the capability string to determine whether a particular parameter is going to be interpreted as a string (whether it matches up with `%l` or `%s`), and whenever that parameter is used, it provides the string.
- ncurses uses a stack for the series of operations (refer to [*Parameterized Strings*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Parameterized-Strings) in the [**`terminfo`** manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html)).

Actually, ncurses uses two passes over the capability string:

1. In the first pass (see [`_nc_tparm_analyze`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/8a51b044a723e15adb3460c362831d90d17df4b8/ncurses/tinfo/lib_tparm.c#L343) in source-code), it steps through the string to see which parameter would be pushed onto the stack, and when it sees a `%l` or `%s`, marks that position in an array `p_is_s[]` as a string.
2. Then in the second pass, ncurses uses [`_nc_tparm_internal`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/8a51b044a723e15adb3460c362831d90d17df4b8/ncurses/tinfo/lib_tparm.c#L472) (shared by  varargs- and a fixed-length argument list functions `tiparm` and [`tparm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Formatting-Output), respectively).  Using the array, it knows whether to handle a zero-parameter as a numeric zero, or an empty string.  Referring to the [source-code](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/8a51b044a723e15adb3460c362831d90d17df4b8/ncurses/tinfo/lib_tparm.c#L216), if asked to pop a *string* where a number was given (or if nothing remains on the stack), ncurses passes back an empty string.

All of that relies upon a correct call to `tparm`, since there is no portable way to determine the number of parameters passed **to** a function, nor actually their **types**.  Unlike `printf`, there is no help from the compiler.  But if the parameter list matches the capability string, ncurses will (probably...) match it.  SVr4 curses does not do this (see for example [`tparm.c` on illumos-gate](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/lib/libcurses/screen/tparm.c)).

In the given example, `%p1%l`

- ncurses expects that a *string* was pushed onto the stack, e.g., using `%p1` (to refer to the first parameter of `tparm` after the capability string), and
- ncurses pops the string value off the stack,
- calls `strlen` to get its length and
- pushes that length (as a number) onto the stack.

That number on the stack can be used in a calculation, e.g.,

```
%p1%l%{1}%+
```

to add 1 to it (pushing the result onto the stack), or just **used** (nothing on the stack) by formatting a number with **`%d`**, etc.

To output a string and its length, again suppose the string is the first parameter, then you can refer to it more than once in the capability string like this

```
%p1%l%d:%p1%s
```

to output a string's length, a colon (**`:`**) separator and the string itself.  The "output" of `tparm` is of course another string, intended to be printed using `putp` or `tputs` because it may have embedded [*padding*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Delays-and-Padding) information (see [*Output Functions*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Output-Functions) in the [terminfo function manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html)).

The operations defined for terminfo came from SVr4, which was officially announced in 1988, though in practice it took several years to become an actuality.  There are no operations defined for string concatenation or substrings; applications have to do that sort of thing for themselves.  What terminfo *does* is to parameterize the numbers, and (not quite as an afterthought) provide for inserting strings in appropriate places.

Comment: thanks for the answer, now I am referring to [this man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo), it would be great if you would elaborate on __ncurses analyzes the capability string to determine whether a particular parameter is going to be interpreted as a string (whether it matches up with %l or %s), and whenever that parameter is used, it provides the string__ with one more example, thanks :)

Comment: Actually, [this man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo) is an example of how to not format a manual page, which I discussed at length [here](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/man2html.html).  I added an authoritative link to my answer.